# How to set the alpha of newly inserted UITableViewCell to 0 for short duration

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating an effect that scrolls a `UITableView` down to the bottom, creates a `UILabel` and places it on top of a `UITextView` where a user has entered their text, and then animates that UILabel onto the new `UITableViewCell's` frame. It is roughly the same effect used when sending a new message in iOS7's default SMS app. I have everything down except for one part, and that is setting the alpha of the newly created `UITableViewCell` to 0 so it looks like blank space as the `UILabel` is animating into it. I've tried the following:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_randomData.count-1 inSection:0];
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.textLabel setAlpha:0.0f];
```

The problem here is that since the `UITableView` is scrolling down to the bottom and inserting the cell, anytime I try to access a specific `UITableViewCell` it is null. If it helps, the animation is triggered by:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

This is used because once the user hits the "send" button, I am using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` to bring the user down to the bottom of the tableview:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_randomData.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

I have tried to set the alpha in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but since all of the cells are recreated as the `UITableView` scrolls down I set all of the reused `UITableViewCell's` alpha to 0 as well which obviously won't work.

So to sum it up, I really just want to set the alpha of a newly created cell to 0 and then set it back to 1 once the animation is complete. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a test in cell for row, if cell = last cell then cell's alpha is 0, or subclass uitableviewcell and put in the initialize method to set the content to be invisible, and then make it visible again when you need it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the easiest way was:

1.) When the "send" button is pressed, disable user interaction

2.) In `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation`, after the button has been pressed, object has been added, and the user is brought to the very bottom of the tableview:

```
CustomCell * cell = [[self.tableView visibleCells] lastObject];
[cell.contentView setAlpha:0.0f];
```

3.) Place the code for the animation right beneath that

4.) Set the cell's alpha back to 1 as well as turn user interaction back on in the animation's completion block.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should set your alpha and animation in 
the following method (see documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So as to make a similar effect I had to store a value in my model telling me if my cell is a newly created cell and use it in the function above like this :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyModelItem* item = [MyModel itemAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(item.wasJustCreated) {
        item.wasJustCreated = NO;
        cell.alpha = 0.0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
            cell.alpha = 1.0;
        }];
    }
}
```

You will have to add a field such as "wasJustCreated" in your cell model item, which is initialized to NO. It may not be the most elegant solution but works as expected and is just easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks for this, it didn't quite work the way I wanted to but it led me to figuring it out my own way.